# Full Screen event on Touch not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, fullscreen

In my mobile app I want to toggle full screen when user is swiping up.
So when `touchend` event is triggered I'm calling  `document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();`
The problem is that it doesn't works for me in mobile Chrome 56+.

Here is example.
https://jsfiddle.net/ibmw/tnncaxj0/6/

The interest part is: this issue appearing only when you make touchmove between touchstart and touchend.

In console I've got an error:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture.
>   document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();

Does anyone know how to struggle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `preventDefault()` on touchmove, and pass [new option](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) to `addEventListener()`. It's works for me:

```
addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, {passive: false});

function onTouchMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault
}
```

Comment: This works because you can no longer trigger fullscreen on touch events **when the user is just using touch to scroll around the page**. This code prevents the scrolling, so the user's swipe is treated as a real interaction.

Comment: Since Chrome 56 the 'touchmove' event will no longer trigger a user gesture and thus can't be used to activate fullscreen mode. You now have to call requestFullscreen() from the 'touchend' event after you have used the above code to prevent the default touch scrolling behavior. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6131337345892352